# How to prove financial or health dependence of non-EU parents on EU citizen?

Tags: eu, family

I'm a German citizen and I'm moving to another EU state for work - Austria. My parents are non-EU and living in their country of origin and are dependent on me health-wise and financial-wise. Once in Austria, I want to apply to get my parents to stay with me there. The requirement is that I need to prove their dependence on me. What are the accepted evidences in such cases? For example, I have been sending money transfers to my parents for almost 6 months now via Western Union. Also my father reached retirement age and their country of origin is considered a war zone (no proper hospitals or medical care). They both have very poor health, but I can't be with them to help because the country is at war and I would be risking my life to be there or even worse get stuck there. Would this be enough evidence to prove their dependence?

The whole idea of me leaving Germany to go to live and work in Austria for one year is to rescue my parents from that war because, unfortunately, Germany refused to get them.

Comment: Hi Melanie. What do you mean by "Germany refused to get them"?

Comment: They applied for a schengen visa and got rejected, then i contacted the immigration office here and they said there is no chance/way/right to get them to germany